# hydro and openni installation

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am not able to install openni package on hydro. Is there any workaround? Since i could see it is not available for the hydro disto.

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni2-camera

[sudo] password for rootx:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following packages will be upgraded:

ros-hydro-openni2-camera

1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 313 not upgraded.

Need to get 441 kB of archives.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ raring/main ros-hydro-openni2-camera i386 0.1.2-0raring-20140311-1903-+0000
404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-hydro-openni2-camera/ros-hydro-openni2-camera_0.1.2-0raring-20140311-1903-+0000_i386.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

-Abhimoh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151461/hydro-and-openni-installation/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested in the error message, you should try a `sudo apt-get update` first. The package it's trying to download is no longer available, there is a newer version instead.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0